# How can I add a new category to a morea site?

Tags: jekyll, morea-framework

I'm trying to add a new 'project' category to a morea based [site](http://jce-il.github.io/se-class16b/index.html), where there will be a page similar to experiences page where I'll collect all course project related experiences and assignments, and maybe even modules.

- Is it ok to look for pages with 'project' in their id or maybe better to tag with a new morea tag?
- Do I need to also create a new entity type called 'project' or just reuse existing entities
- In MoreaGeneraor.rb I couldn't find where module level page collections are prepared, like for example `module_page.data['morea_experiences']`.
  I thought of preparing a similar collection of `'morea_project'` pages and then traversing it in the new project page.
  Is that done outside of this .rb file? by Jekyll? so how do I inject my collection.
- Any simpler idea?...

Thank

p.s. I've also added the following (from line 3) to 'processMoreaFile()', but it does not seem to be visible at later stages:

```
elsif new_page.data['morea_type'] == "assessment"
        site.config['morea_assessment_pages'] << new_page
            if new_page.data['morea_id'].include?('project')
                site.config['morea_project_pages'] << new_page
                puts "--- project page #{new_page.data['morea_id']}\n "
            end
```

but still do not know where to let each module page find out about it's 'project' pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cool idea.  The simplest approach is to avoid making changes to MoreaGenerator.rb, and instead do it using normal Jekyll mechanisms. Here's a sketch:

1. Add a morea_label called "Project" to each associated module, reading, experience, and assessment.
2. In `master/src`, create a new directory called `project`, containing a file called `index.md`.  This adds a new top-level page to your site (i.e. `http://example.com/ics101/project/index.html`)
3. Implement the index.md file with liquid tags to create the desired page layout for your project page.  For inspiration, see the index.md files in the other top-level pages (readings, experiences, etc.).  You can [access YAML content in Liquid](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/#custom-variables).
4. Once you've got your rocking project page done, you'll want a link to it in the navbar. See [add a menu item](http://morea-framework.github.io/userguide.html#Addamenuitem) for instructions.

Good luck!  If you get it working to your satisfaction, please post its link as a followup to this question so we can see how it turned out!

Comment: Thanks, I had to play a little with traversing the label collection but much simple then the route I started taking...
New project page is here: http://jce-il.github.io/se-class16b/project/
(It is localized into Hebrew with right-to-left style, the relevant menu item is 'פרויקט')